# Activiti: unit test failure behavior

Tags: junit, activiti

I am running unit tests for activiti based code. I face very strange behaviour.

I have two separate test files, and test in both have almost similar code. Both start with:

```
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
        .createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
        .buildProcessEngine();
```

Strangely, one of the test completes successfully. But other one fails with 
error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost"

One test always passes, while other one always fails with this error.

What can be the cause for this behaviour?

PS: I spotted a difference. Failing code calls 'createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration' while passing code calls 'createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration'.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has much to deal with your Database setup. `createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration` - will create an in memory DB for you using spring configuration, so you don't have to worry much about its config. however, when you use `createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration` it looks configuration for an external DB (that should already be set up and running). when it does not find such config the engine throws exception(s) as you mentioned.